Using C std headers in c++ mode, how to specifiy C version
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdckdint.h>
#include <stdint.h>
//#include <stdbool.h> // needed when compiled as c++ with -std=c++23

int main()
{
    int64_t value1 = 34;
    int32_t value2 = 177;
    uint8_t result;
    bool overflowed = ckd_add(&result, value1, value2);
    if (overflowed) {
        printf("result overflowed\n");
    } else {
        printf("result is %hhu\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}

The above code compiles fine with GCC when compiled as C with -std=C23, but it does not compile as C++ with -std=c++23.
See https://godbolt.org/z/Tsf7MahPe
The error is
<source>:13:23: error: '_Bool' was not declared in this scope
   13 |     bool overflowed = ckd_add(&result, value1, value2);

Seems ironic that you have to include <stdbool.h> in C++ but not in C :D.
-> Is it possible to specify C23 mode (or any other mode, in particular for GCC) when using C std libraries in C++?
(my assumption is this error arises because the C lib is not in C23 mode and thus does not have bool and _Bool)
Edit: My assumption was wrong. The C version is already C23 otherwise ckd_add should not be available. The original question is not answered yet, though.

Build C code as C, build C++ code as C++. Don't mix and match the two different languages (and yes, C and C++ are two very different languages).

"Seems ironic that you have to include <stdbool.h> in C++ but not in C :D." Simply include for both languages. Whit is the problem and is it "ironic"? (I do not see any irony)

Each version of the C++ standard incorporates a specific version of the C standard by reference. It makes no provision for choosing which C version to use. A specific C++ implementation might choose to provide that as a feature (that deviates from the C++ standard), but generally, you must write your code to conform the the C++ standard and its paired C version, not make the version of C conform to your code.

fyi  C++ Draft Standard -  [diff] "...Subclause [diff.iso] lists the differences between C++ and C, in addition to those listed above, by the chapters of this document...."

Each version of C++ refers to a specific version of C as normative reference.
For example C++23 refer to C17. So anything added later to C is not going to be part of C++23 either way (except if there happens to be convergent evolution such that the standards happen to specify the same feature independently of one another).
Even if C++23 refers to C17, that doesn't mean that all C17 features are supported in C++23. Instead, the C++ standard mentions explicitly what is and isn't incorporated into C++.
You can't expect to be able to use C standard library functions that are not incorporated into C++ in C++ code. There is no meaning in which you can mix and match C and C++ versions either.
So, you aren't guaranteed that <stdckdint.h> or the functions declared in it will work in C++ in any version or with any compiler configuration. If it is supported in some way, then that's the compiler being forthcoming and purely a compiler-specific extension. You can of course petition your compiler writers nicely if they could write the C library functions in such a way that they are also usable in C++ code. That's up to them.
It is really important to understand that these are two distinct languages that just have a certain common subset due to their origin. There are also some efforts to maintain or extend that common subset, but both languages otherwise develop independently from one another.

Where can I find which version of C++ "uses" which version of C?

@user765269 At the beginning of the standard document in [intro.refs], e.g. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/intro.refs#1.3.

But if C++23 references C17, it seems odd that <stdckdint.h> is available which is only available since C23.

@user765269 That header is not part of C++23, so the compiler can do with it what it wants in C++23 mode. Yes, they could have #ifdefed it out when compiling in C++ mode. I don't think it is intentional that the declarations are both visible but also non-functional in C++. But that's a matter specific to the implementation.

@user765269 In this specific case, I guess the header file belongs to glibc or some other C library implementation that your system is using. You could ask them whether that is intentional.

The header might become part of C++ 26. P3370R1: Add new library headers from C23

@BoP If they are on track to be included in C++26 then that's even more of an indicator that the behavior OP sees is unintentional (or at least it must be fixed by the library implementer eventually anyway).

In C++, the _Bool type from C is not defined by default because the language provides its own bool type as a built-in, native type. The C++ language design intentionally separates itself from some of C's legacy features. Here's why _Bool is not available by default in C++23
_Bool is retained in the C++ language as part of the C compatibility layer. If you include <stdbool.h> in a C++ program, it defines bool as an alias for _Bool, along with true and false.
On the contrary _Bool is a built-in type in C23, as it has been since C99. The C language explicitly defines _Bool as a fundamental type, used to represent Boolean values (true and false).
That is the reason why you have to include stdbool.h when compiling as C++
So if you want to use this header - you will have to accept it or write something more C++ish

template <typename T>
constexpr bool ckd_add(T a, T b, T& result)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>, "ckd_add only supports integral types");

    bool no_overflow = true;

    if ((b > 0) && (a > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - b))
    {
        no_overflow = false;
    }
    else if ((b < 0) && (a < std::numeric_limits<T>::min() - b))
    {
        no_overflow = false;
    }
    else
    {
        result = a + b;
    }

    return no_overflow;
}


According to the spec, bool is a built-in type in C23, too, with _Bool now being categorized as an obsolescent "alternative spelling".  That's why the OP finds that they don't need to #include <stdbool.h> when they compile for C23.  That they find they do need it when compiling for C++23 suggests some kind of weirdness related to the other C standard library headers they are including.

I do understand your comment. My answer says C has _Bool, C++ does not. To use _Bool i C++ you need an include. Do you argue with it? Ossolence does not mean not existence.

Read the code in the question.  The OP uses bool, not _Bool.  The only way _Bool gets introduced into that code is from one of the included headers.  But _Bool is obsolescent in C23, so it's a little surprising for C23 standard library headers to be using it.

@JohnBollinger read answer before commenting. What did  I write? That you need it if you want to use this header as it defines it as (_Bool) __builtin_add_overflow (. Of course it is possible that another implementation will use bool , but gnu one used by GCC uses _Bool

"Bool is retained in the C++ language as part of the C compatibility layer.": I don't think that is correct. According to the C++ standard the content of <stdbool.h> are the same as in C except that bool, false and true are not defined. Because _Bool is a fundamental type, it isn't part of <stdbool.h>. But it is a reserved identifier in C++, so an implementation could support it as a convenience either way (whether or not <stdbool.h> is included).

@user17732522 "Because _Bool is a fundamental type..." - not in C++. C++ standard does not know anything about _Bool. You you  think you are right - find the evidence in C++ standard

Yes, but C++ specifies the contents of <stdbool.h> in terms of the contents of the same header as specified in C and in C it doesn't contain any declaration of _Bool. And the standard doesn't mention _Bool at all explicitly.

"_C++ standard does not know anything about Bool": Well yes, exactly, but you make it sound like including <stdbool.h> would guarantee _Bool to be usable, when it seems to just be a compiler-specific extension.

stdckdint.h is a C header, defined in the C23 standard. It was not meant to be used in a C++ program. In this case, it fails because it tries to use _Bool, which (as other answers and comments point out) does not exist in C++.
Headers from the C++ standard library can be recognized because they have no file extension, for example cstdint instead of stdint.h. Unfortunately there is no C++ equivalent of stdckdint.h (yet?).

Although it is certainly recommended practice in C++ to use C++ headers for C standard library functions, it generally is not required to do so.

It would be surprising (but not impossible) for the issue to be in stdckint.h, as this is new in C23, along with the obsolescence of the spelling _Bool.  In C23, bool is a built-in type.

@JohnBollinger GCC's stdckdint.h, as of version 14.2.1, assumes the existence of _Bool without including any header to define it. It contains no extern "C" block either.

@Thomas that indicates  there's no support for C++ interaction. I guess there's no conditional complication present either. Since C23 is not C++23, that makes sence. But again the platform may decide to support some C23 features in C++23 mode too.

Others have already answered your question, I'll just say that you can use predefined macros to conditionally include <stdbool.h> like so:
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #include <stdbool.h> // needed when compiled with -std=c++23
#endif

The __STDC_VERSION__ macro will expand to a similar value, specifying a C standard used.
Official docs.
